# Kohana ORM change timezone on select

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

Is that possible to select from Database using different timezone ?
I got some record in my table that thier `time` colum is timestamp of GMT timezone.
And I want to get all the records from `30-05-2013` for example. using the PST timezone.

I googled abit and found out that if i'm running this query:

```
SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
```

Before every query it should work (Correct me if i'm wrong).

But what can I do with Kohana ORM?

This is my Model:

```
class Model_Calls extends ORM {

    protected $_table_name = 'pbxlog';
    protected $_has_many = array('user' => array('model' => 'user'));

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            'logtime' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
            ),
            'user_id' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
            ),
            'customer' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'server' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'callid' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'uniqueid' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'state' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'src_type' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'src_number' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'src_customer' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'dst_type' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'dst_number' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'dst_customer' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'called_type' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
            'called_number' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 1)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's enough to run `SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';` right after you established a connection.

Comment: @claustrofob - Thank you for your quick response. any idea where should I add this call in Kohana framework?

Comment: Unfortunately i am not familiar with Kohana. Somebody will definitely help you.

Comment: So your `Model_Calls` has all entries in GMT but all other models have their entries in PST? I was just looking over the source files of ORM and in `_initialize()` you get the db connection. You need to know when one model did all their tasks since db is implemented as singleton. However you could create a new instance that is using the required timezone and then modify the `_initialize()` method of some of your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy but doable (not tested though).
1. You should add `get_connection()` method in the `Database` class (put it directly in your `application/classes/` folder, file name should be `database.php`):

```
class Database extends Kohana_Database 
{
   public function get_connection()
   {
      return $this->_connection;
   }
}
```

2. You should override `__construct()` method in your model:

```
class Model_Calls extends ORM {
public function __construct($id = NULL, $timezone = NULL)
{
    $this->_initialize();

    // ADDED
    if ($timezone)
    {
        $this->_db->get_connection()->exec('SET time_zone = ' . $this->_db->quote($timezone));
    }
    // END ADDED

    if ($id !== NULL)
    {
        if (is_array($id))
        {
            foreach ($id as $column => $value)
            {
                // Passing an array of column => values
                $this->where($column, '=', $value);
            }

            $this->find();
        }
        else
        {
            // Passing the primary key
            $this->where($this->_object_name . '.' . $this->_primary_key, '=', $id)->find();
        }
    }
    elseif (!empty($this->_cast_data))
    {
        // Load preloaded data from a database call cast
        $this->_load_values($this->_cast_data);

        $this->_cast_data = array();
    }
}
```

Now you can load your records like this:

```
$res = ORM::factory('call', NULL, 'America/Los_Angeles')->get_all_calls_I_need(xxxxx);
```

Note that this will not work when you use Query Builder calls.
In such case you will need to set time_zone manually before executing the right query.